# Как вертикально выровнять весь текст в CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема, по-видимому, в том, что некоторые буквы, такие как: ***g, y, q*** и т. д., которые имеют хвост, расположенный вниз, не допускают вертикального центрирования.
Вот изображение, демонстрирующее проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буквы в зеленой рамке в основном идеальны, так как у них нет нисходящего хвоста.
Те, что в красной рамке, демонстрируют проблему.

Я хотел бы, чтобы все символы были идеально центрированы по вертикали.
На изображении символы с направленным вниз хвостом не центрированы по вертикали.
Возможно ли это исправить?

Вот [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urs2j3d5/), полностью демонстрирующий проблему.

```css
.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(81, 75, 93);
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.character {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">W</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">y</div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to vertically align all text in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58924157/7394871) от участника  [@Chron Bag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6353002/chron-bag).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58924157/7394871

Comment: Добрый вечер, Александр, вот такой нестандартный вопрос от меня, это что-то вроде перевод английских вопросов на русском? Мне интерестно)

Comment: @ПростаMiha Здравствуй Михаил. Да, именно так  Нахожу интересные на мой взгляд вопросы-ответы и перевожу. Но что-то в последнее время люди вяло интересуются. Хотя вот здесь реализована оч. интересная техника

Answer (score 2):

Вот мое решение с использованием JS. Идея состоит в том, чтобы преобразовать элемент в изображение, чтобы получить его данные в виде пикселей, а затем просмотреть их, чтобы найти верх и низ каждого символа и применить `translation` для выполнения выравнивания. Это будет работать с динамическими свойствами шрифта.

Код не оптимизирован, но выделяет основную идею:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".avatar");

var fixes = [];


for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  var current = elems[i];
  domtoimage.toPixelData(current)
    .then(function(im) {
      /* Search for the top limit */
      var t = 0;
      for (var y = 0; y < current.scrollHeight; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < current.scrollWidth; ++x) {
          var j = (4 * y * current.scrollHeight) + (4 * x);
          if (im[j] == 255 && im[j + 1] == 255 && im[j + 2] == 255) {
            t = y;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      /* Поиск нижнего предела*/
      var b = 0;
      for (var y = (current.scrollHeight - 1); y >= 0; --y) {
        for (var x = (current.scrollWidth - 1); x >= 0; --x) {
          var j = (4 * y * current.scrollHeight) + (4 * x);
          if (im[j] == 255 && im[j + 1] == 255 && im[j + 2] == 255) {
            b = current.scrollHeight - y;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      /* получить разницу и применить translation*/
      var diff = (b - t)/2;
      fixes.push(diff);
      /* применяем translation, когда все подсчитано*/
      if(fixes.length == elems.length) {
        for (var k = 0; k < elems.length; k++) {
          elems[k].querySelector('.character').style.transform = "translateY(" + fixes[k] + "px)";
        }
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat,
    rgb(81, 75, 93);
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.character {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-challenges.com/wp-content/themes/ronneby_child/js/dom-to-image.js"></script>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">W</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">y</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-size:35px">a</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-size:25px">2</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">o</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">|</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">@</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">Â</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-family:arial">Q</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">~</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">8</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">ä</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">ç</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">$</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">></div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">%</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Вот первая оптимизация кода:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".avatar");
var k = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  domtoimage.toPixelData(elems[i])
    .then(function(im) {
     var l = im.length;
      /* Поиск верхнего предела */
      var t = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < l; j+=4) {
          if (im[j+1] == 255) { /* Поскольку мы знаем цвета, мы можем протестировать только составляющую G. */
            t = Math.ceil((j/4)/125);
            break;
          }
      }
      /* Поиск нижнего предела*/
      var b = 0;
      for (var j = l - 1; j >= 0; j-=4) {
          if (im[j+1] == 255) {
            b = 125 - Math.ceil((j/4)/125);
            break;
          }
      }
      /* получить разницу и применить translation*/
      elems[k].querySelector('.character').style.transform = "translateY(" + (b - t)/2 + "px)";
      k++;
    });
}
```

```css
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat,
    rgb(81, 75, 93);
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.character {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css-challenges.com/wp-content/themes/ronneby_child/js/dom-to-image.js"></script>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">W</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">y</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-size:35px">a</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-size:25px">2</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">o</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">|</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">@</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">Â</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character" style="font-family:arial">Q</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">~</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">8</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">ä</div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">ç</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">$</div>
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">></div>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <div class="character">%</div>
</div>
```

Для этого я использую плагин [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image).

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925003/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>